# Multiple ASPX Pages using the same JavaScript / CSS Scripts

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am using the same CSS links and JavaScript scripts on numerous Web Forms ASPX pages on my website. So the head section of my pages are practically the same, bar a few exceptions.

I was told to look at Master Pages for Web Forms.

Is there somewhere I can store the duplicated scripts/links, and call them on each page, rather than placing the links in each head section?

Comment: From this **Is there somewhere I can store the duplicated scripts/links** what do you mean?

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain I was told that it's not good to keep calling the same links in the head sections of different ASPX pages. Is this correct?

Comment: You dont have a master page?

Comment: @Sweg There is nothing wrong to call the same links on multiple HTML (in your case ASPX) pages. The browser will cache them locally for you (depending on the cache settings of the file). There are many advantages and disadvantages involved in HTML resource management, however, a general statement like that is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use masterPage head protion where you have to place links only once and by binding pages to this master page links will get attached with all pages.If you want any other link other than this you can use content place holder in head portion and use that in the particular page